# React Addup number During LongPress buttom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, long-press

I have two Button (Add and mines) that I want as long as I press the **Add button** it constantly Adds to the center **number** and also the longer I press it, it adds faster

[image]

> I tried **setTimeout** and **setInterval** but did not worked.

this is what I have, any suggestions?

```
const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
```

--

```
     <IconButton onClick={handlePlus} className="payout__icon-button">
     <Add />
     </IconButton>

     {amount}

     <IconButton onClick={handleMinus} className="payout__icon-button">
     <Remove />
     </IconButton>
```

--

```
const AMOUNT_UNIT = 10000;
function handlePlus() {
        let val;        
        val = amount + AMOUNT_UNIT;
        setAmount(val);
    
    }

    function handleMinus() {
        var val = 0;
        val = amount - AMOUNT_UNIT;
        setAmount(val);
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
yarn add use-long-press // or
npm install --save use-long-press

import React from 'react';
import { useLongPress } from 'use-long-press';

const Example = () => {
  const bind = useLongPress(() => {
    console.log('Long pressed!');
    val = amount + AMOUNT_UNIT * 3;
  });

  return <button {...bind}>Press me</button>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you but it's only added one time until I press it again. I need the button keep adding as long as I hold it.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer myself this works really well for me and on long-press keep adding and speeding up the more you hold the button.

I use this package:

```
yarn add use-long-press // or
npm install --save use-long-press
```

these are my functions:

```
    let myTimeout;
    let longpressActive = false;
    let onPressValue = 0;
    let n = 200; // this is 200ms for interval func

    function stopInterval() {
        clearInterval(myTimeout);
        if (longpressActive) {
            setAmount(parseInt(onPressValue)); // bind on press data
            longpressActive = false; 
        }
    }

// for onclick func
function handlePlus() {
        let val;
        val = amount + AMOUNT_UNIT;
        setAmount(val);
    }

// for longPress func
function increment() {
    longpressActive = true; //Stop the interval in essence
    let myInputRef = document.querySelector(".payout__price");

    onPressValue = parseInt(amount);
    myTimeout = setInterval(function runIncrement() {
        //Start the timeout which is really a controlled interval

        
        if (onPressValue < props.balance) {
            onPressValue += AMOUNT_UNIT;
            myInputRef.innerText = onPressValue;
            if (n > 60) {
                n = n - 20;
            }
            
            clearInterval(myTimeout);
            myTimeout = setTimeout(runIncrement, parseInt(n));
        } else {
            clearInterval(myTimeout);
            setAmount(parseInt(props.balance));
            chengeCurve(props.balance);
        }
        // setAmount(amount+50);
    }, n); //Start the interval with an initial time of 35 milliseconds
    //Now we know when the interval started, and we can
}

 const Add_Long_Press_plus = useLongPress(() => {
            console.log("Long pressed!");
            increment();
            //  val = amount + AMOUNT_UNIT * 3;
        });
```

And this is my JSX:

```
 <IconButton
 onClick={handlePlus}
 onMouseUp={stopInterval}
 className="payout__icon-button"
 >
   <Add {...Add_Long_Press_plus} />
 </IconButton>
 <div className="payout__price">{amount}</div>
```